# Migrating from Circleci to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, migration, bitbucket, circleci

i have few bit-bucket repositories, and till now i have used circle-ci config files to run test-build-deploy.
Now we migrating to Jenkins, and i don't want to build all the steps from beginning
Is there a simple way to convert circle-ci config files to Jenkins jobs. 
I have already created a Jenkins instance, and attached the bit-bucket account to it